# Кому задавать атрибуты, потомку или родителю?

Tags: css

Какая структура с точки зрения CSS правильная?
Вариант 1:

```
.blocks {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}
.block {}
```

Вариант 2:

```
.blocks {
    width: 200px;
}
.block {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Первая, если они не ссылки.

Comment: Чем аргументируете?

Comment: Внутренним чувством прекрасного)))

Answer (score 0):

Если это просто DIV'ы и в стилях нужно назначить только размер текста и цвет, то нужно всего лишь это:

```
.blocks {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Таким образом файл CSS будет меньше в размере.